# Troubleshooting installing yomen. Can anyone help me in solving this issue..!

Tags: node.js, macos, ubuntu

~ $ npm install -g yo

npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0

npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"

npm ERR! node v0.12.5

npm ERR! npm  v2.14.0

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo'

npm ERR!     at Error (native)

npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo']

npm ERR!   errno: -13,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo' }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo'

npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)

npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo']

npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,

npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /Users/Jagadeesh/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Instead run the command as `npm install -g yo`.  The error you are getting says:

"npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

You will need to run as root to install this.